# Fetching Email in Twisted using IMAP

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to fetch emails on a gmail account using twisted, and to say the least it has been a pain, looking at email is their a clear explanation and structure (it seems hacked together at best). I am trying to grab attachments yet the attachment isn't any where in sight.

I am using the example IMAP Client from twisted and modified it, I am using fetchAll('1:*') to get the email and then getting the first email but I can't find the email attachment that is on that email (I checked it is there in google). Also what is with the 1:* and I can't seem to find any thing that actually explains email (as though no one understands it)

So Stackoverflow, what am I missing?

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


"""
    Simple IMAP4 client which displays the subjects of all messages in a
    particular mailbox.
    """

import sys

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import ssl
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import stdio
from twisted.mail import imap4
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.python import util
from twisted.python import log



class TrivialPrompter(basic.LineReceiver):
    from os import linesep as delimiter

    promptDeferred = None

    def prompt(self, msg):
        assert self.promptDeferred is None
        self.display(msg)
        self.promptDeferred = defer.Deferred()
        return self.promptDeferred

    def display(self, msg):
        self.transport.write(msg)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.promptDeferred is None:
            return
        d, self.promptDeferred = self.promptDeferred, None
        d.callback(line)



class SimpleIMAP4Client(imap4.IMAP4Client):
    """
        A client with callbacks for greeting messages from an IMAP server.
        """
    greetDeferred = None

    def serverGreeting(self, caps):
        self.serverCapabilities = caps
        if self.greetDeferred is not None:
            d, self.greetDeferred = self.greetDeferred, None
            d.callback(self)



class SimpleIMAP4ClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    usedUp = False

    protocol = SimpleIMAP4Client


    def __init__(self, username, onConn):
        self.ctx = ssl.ClientContextFactory()

        self.username = username
        self.onConn = onConn


    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        """
            Initiate the protocol instance. Since we are building a simple IMAP
            client, we don't bother checking what capabilities the server has. We
            just add all the authenticators twisted.mail has.  Note: Gmail no
            longer uses any of the methods below, it's been using XOAUTH since
            2010.
            """
        assert not self.usedUp
        self.usedUp = True

        p = self.protocol(self.ctx)
        p.factory = self
        p.greetDeferred = self.onConn

        p.registerAuthenticator(imap4.PLAINAuthenticator(self.username))
        p.registerAuthenticator(imap4.LOGINAuthenticator(self.username))
        p.registerAuthenticator(
                                imap4.CramMD5ClientAuthenticator(self.username))

        return p


    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        d, self.onConn = self.onConn, None
        d.errback(reason)



def cbServerGreeting(proto, username, password):
    """
        Initial callback - invoked after the server sends us its greet message.
        """
    # Hook up stdio
    tp = TrivialPrompter()
    stdio.StandardIO(tp)

    # And make it easily accessible
    proto.prompt = tp.prompt
    proto.display = tp.display

    # Try to authenticate securely
    return proto.authenticate(password
                              ).addCallback(cbAuthentication, proto
                                            ).addErrback(ebAuthentication, proto, username, password
                                                         )


def ebConnection(reason):
    """
        Fallback error-handler. If anything goes wrong, log it and quit.
        """
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    log.err(reason)
    return reason


def cbAuthentication(result, proto):
    """
        Callback after authentication has succeeded.

        Lists a bunch of mailboxes.
        """
    return proto.list("", "*"
                      ).addCallback(cbMailboxList, proto
                                    )


def ebAuthentication(failure, proto, username, password):
    """
        Errback invoked when authentication fails.

        If it failed because no SASL mechanisms match, offer the user the choice
        of logging in insecurely.

        If you are trying to connect to your Gmail account, you will be here!
        """
    failure.trap(imap4.NoSupportedAuthentication)
    return proto.prompt(
                        "No secure authentication available. Login insecurely? (y/N) "
                        ).addCallback(cbInsecureLogin, proto, username, password
                                      )


def cbInsecureLogin(result, proto, username, password):
    """
        Callback for "insecure-login" prompt.
        """
    if result.lower() == "y":
        # If they said yes, do it.
        return proto.login(username, password
                           ).addCallback(cbAuthentication, proto
                                         )
    return defer.fail(Exception("Login failed for security reasons."))


def cbMailboxList(result, proto):
    """
        Callback invoked when a list of mailboxes has been retrieved.
        """
    result = [e[2] for e in result]
    s = '\n'.join(['%d. %s' % (n + 1, m) for (n, m) in zip(range(len(result)), result)])
    if not s:
        return defer.fail(Exception("No mailboxes exist on server!"))
    return proto.prompt(s + "\nWhich mailbox? [1] "
                        ).addCallback(cbPickMailbox, proto, result
                                      )


def cbPickMailbox(result, proto, mboxes):
    """
        When the user selects a mailbox, "examine" it.
        """
    mbox = mboxes[int(result or '1') - 1]
    return proto.examine(mbox
                         ).addCallback(cbExamineMbox, proto
                                       )


def cbExamineMbox(result, proto):
    """
        Callback invoked when examine command completes.

        Retrieve the subject header of every message in the mailbox.
        """
    # FETCH ALL HEADERS? WHERE IS A ONE FOR AN ATTACHMENT
    return proto.fetchAll('1:*').addCallback(cbFetch, proto)


def cbFetch(result, proto):
    """
        Finally, display headers.
        """
    if result:
        keys = result.keys()
        keys.sort()
        k = keys[-1]
        proto.display('%s %s' % (k, result[k]))
    else:
        print "Hey, an empty mailbox!"

    return proto.logout()


def cbClose(result):
    """
        Close the connection when we finish everything.
        """
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.stop()


def main():
    hostname = raw_input('IMAP4 Server Hostname: ')
    port = raw_input('IMAP4 Server Port (the default is 143, 993 uses SSL): ')
    username = raw_input('IMAP4 Username: ')
    password = util.getPassword('IMAP4 Password: ')

    onConn = defer.Deferred(
    ).addCallback(cbServerGreeting, username, password
                  ).addErrback(ebConnection
                               ).addBoth(cbClose)

    factory = SimpleIMAP4ClientFactory(username, onConn)

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    if port == '993':
        reactor.connectSSL(hostname, int(port), factory, ssl.ClientContextFactory())
    else:
        if not port:
            port = 143
        reactor.connectTCP(hostname, int(port), factory)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, imap4 is a (perhaps needlessly) complex protocol for mail handling, and twisted's client implementation is (necessarily) complex to fully support that protocol.  To get much of anywhere, you should consider spending some time reading the standard that explains the protocol: [rfc3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) and the relevent parts of [twisted's api](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.mail.imap4.IMAP4Client.html).

That said, it looks like you're using `IMAP4Client.fetchAll()`, which, paradoxically, fetches "envelope" data, the headers and metadata about the message.  the comparable call that returns the body of the email, too, is actually `fetchFull()`.

Comment: See in particular <http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5>: "ALL ... Macro equivalent to: (FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE)"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointers to RFC3501 and RFC822 by SingleNegationElimination and Jean-Paul, I think I have a better understanding of how to achieve this.

The solution I found is to the API `fetchSpecific` [source code](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/mail/imap4.py#L4266) of `imap4`. You can specify which "part" of the message (i.e. a mail in your inbox) to retrieve. For attachment, the content of the attached file(s) is embedded in the `TEXT` part and encoded with base64. In my particular example, there is a pdf attachment in the mail, and

```
proto.fetchSpecific(imap4.MessageSet(247), uid=True, headerType='TEXT').addCallback(cbViewAttachment, proto)

def cbViewAttachment(result, proto):
    for k, value in result.items():
        print(value[0][4][:400])
        ...
```

gives something like

```
------_CANON_2007111239350128_
Content-Type: Application/pdf;
 name="0128_20200711123935_001.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="0128_20200711123935_001.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

JVBERi0xLjYKJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwgCi9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAyMDA3MTEyMDM5
MThaMDAnMDAnKQovQ3JlYXRvciAoXDM3NlwzNzdcMDAwQ1wwMDBhXDAwMG5cMDAwb1wwMDBuXDAw
MCBcMDAwTVwwMDBGXDAwMDJcMDAwNFw
```

Some quick explanation. The above code does fetch the `TEXT` part of the message with UID = 247. Upon success of the call to `fetchSpecific`, `cbDownloadAttachment` is called, where the first argument is a dictionary of `TEXT` parts - one entry for each of the specified message. In this case there is only one message being specified, so the `result` will just be a dictionary with one single entry corresponding to the UID = 247 message.

The actual attachment content is embedded in the `[0][4]` of the value of the entry. It looks like above. It is almost obvious that the `JVB...` part is the base64-encoded content. I tried to decode the first small portion of it with `base64` and it looks like

```
%PDF-1.6\n%\xe2\xe3
```

which means that this is actually the beginning of a PDF file.

You can then write the content to a local file so as to "download" the attachment. In the above example it is basically

```
with open('your/file/name', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(value[0][4][213:]))
```

Note that 213 is hard-coded as the start of the content. In the real-world case you should definitely parse the `TEXT` a bit to find it out.

Hope this helps someone in the similar situation as me.